# Hbase replication not copy data

Tags: hbase, replication

I have 2 hbase cluster named A and B , each cluster have 3 machines, i want to enable replication between the 2 cluster, here is the step

Add config to **hbase-site.xml**

```
<property>
    <name>hbase.replication</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
```

In master cluster A, add peer

```
add_peer '2',"wxmaster1,wxmaster2,wxslave1:2181:/hbase2"
```

this return success, as I can see in log , cluster A master log have init the session connection to cluster B regionservers.

Create the same table in cluster A and B

```
create 'test_replication', {NAME => 'cf', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '1', VERSIONS => '2', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'TRUE'}
```

Then I think everything should be ok, any change at cluster A table 'test_replication' will copy to cluster B, while it not, and no any error log.

Here is the results for `status 'replication'`
[image]

```
2017-02-16 18:31:34,570 WARN  [regionserver/wxmaster2/172.16.178.78:16021.logRoller] regionserver.ReplicationSource: Queue size: 3 exceeds value of replication.source.log.queue.warn: 2
2017-02-16 18:31:34,572 INFO  [regionserver/wxmaster2/172.16.178.78:16021.logRoller] wal.FSHLog: Archiving hdfs://cluster1/hbase/WALs/wxmaster2,16021,1487233892284/wxmaster2%2C16021%2C1487233892284.default.1487233894071 to hdfs://cluster1/hbase/oldWALs/wxmaster2%2C16021%2C1487233892284.default.1487233894071
2017-02-16 18:31:34,586 INFO  [regionserver/wxmaster2/172.16.178.78:16021.logRoller] wal.FSHLog: Archiving hdfs://cluster1/hbase/WALs/wxmaster2,16021,1487233892284/wxmaster2%2C16021%2C1487233892284.default.1487237494395 to hdfs://cluster1/hbase/oldWALs/wxmaster2%2C16021%2C1487233892284.default.1487237494395
2017-02-16 18:36:33,914 INFO  [LruBlockCacheStatsExecutor] hfile.LruBlockCache: totalSize=1.65 MB, freeSize=1.57 GB, max=1.57 GB, blockCount=0, accesses=0, hits=0, hitRatio=0, cachingAccesses=0, cachingHits=0, cachingHitsRatio=0,evictions=749, evicted=0, evictedPerRun=0.0
2017-02-16 18:36:34,394 INFO  [wxmaster2:16021Replication Statistics #0] regionserver.Replication: Normal source for cluster 2: Total replicated edits: 0, currently replicating from: null at position: 0
```

anybody can help me?

And, I am using

hadoop-2.5.2
hbase-1.0.1
zookeeper-3.4.6

Answer (score 0):

finnaly I solved the problem , due to my add_peer command error, the znode did not exists, should be

add_peer '2',"wxmaster1,wxmaster2,wxslave1:2181:/hbase"